# Rendering multiple webpack entry points in same page with shared react library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hooks

I have a react application, where I have configured multiple entry points in my webpack config.

Sample

```
const webpackConfig = {
entry: {
    A: "./app/activity/a.js",
    B: "./app/activity/b.js",
    C: "./app/activity/c.tsx",
    D: "./app/activity/d.tsx",
  },
}
```

Sample Activity file

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { WidgetComponentA } from "../components/WidgetA";

render(
      <WidgetComponentA />,
    document.getElementById("widget-root-div")
);
```

Here, on my page, I require to render these multiple entry points in a widget model, these require to be rendered together.

I am facing below issue here when rendering them together

```
Invariant Violation: Minified React error #321
https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321
```

I have verified that I am not breaking any rules of hooks.

While rendering, I see that if i check `webpackjsonP` value, it misses one of the widgets entry point i.e essentially, if order is A and B, then only B will render but webpackJsonP will only have A in it and vice versa if order is reversed.

**Note** - Some entry points are in JS and some in Typescript.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

After further investigation, found that issue only comes up with react-hooks when multiple widgets render together.
Moving to class components resolved issue. Though haven't been able to identify the root cause.

Comment: You neglected to include your render method.

Comment: Added render method.